# _compute_qty: unexisting method in product_uom class Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo-10, erp

I'm trying to upgrade own custom module from ***odoo8*** to ***odoo10***.

i got this error:
**AttributeError**: **'product.uom'** object has no method '**_compute_qty**'

```
@api.model
    def _prepare_purchase_order_line(self, po, item):
        po_line_obj = self.env['purchase.order.line']
        product_uom = self.env['product.uom']
        product = item.product_id
        default_uom_po_id = product.uom_po_id.id
        qty = product_uom._compute_qty(item.product_uom_id.id,
                                       item.product_qty,
                                       default_uom_po_id, round=True)
`'
```

Answer (score 0):

Between odoo8 and odoo10, obviously there is lot of code rewriting. Methods and functions that change names and signatures. It is exactly the case here.
**_compute_qty(.....)** becomes **_compute_quantity(.....)**

```
`@api.model
    def _prepare_purchase_order_line(self, po, item):
        po_line_obj = self.env['purchase.order.line']
        product_uom = self.env['product.uom']
        product = item.product_id
        default_uom_po_id = product.uom_po_id.id
        qty = product_uom._compute_quantity(item.product_uom_id.id,
                                       item.product_qty,
                                       default_uom_po_id, round=True)
`'`
```